# .create is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am working on two factor authentication using Nodejs, postgresql and express. I have written code for sending One Time Password to email, I'm using `nodemailer` and `otpGenerator` to generate and send OTP to mail, OTP is genarating successfully but one error is coming while testing Postman that error is `OTP.create is not a function`.
and also I used `sequelize` in this application.

Here I'm sharing code and images

**API**

```
const OTP = require('sequelize');
const router = require('express').Router();
const encode = require("../middlewares/crypto");
var otpGenerator = require('otp-generator');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

exports.otpEmail = [async(req, res, next) => {
    try{
            const {email,type} = req.body;
            let email_subject, email_message

           //Generate OTP 
    const otp = otpGenerator.generate(4, {digits:true, lowerCaseAlphabets:false, upperCaseAlphabets:false, alphabets: false, upperCase: false, specialChars: false });
    const now = new Date();
    const expiration_time = addMinutesToDate(now,10);
    
   console.log("\n\nOTP expire time is : "+expiration_time,"\n\nOne Time Password is : "+otp)
  //Create OTP instance in DB
    const otp_instance = await OTP.create({
      otp: otp,
      expiration_time: expiration_time
    });

    console.log(otp_instance.toJSON())

    // Create details object containing the email and otp id
    var details={
        "timestamp": now, 
        "check": email,
        "success": true,
        "message":"OTP sent to user",
        "otp_id": otp_instance.id
      }

      // Encrypting the details 
    const encoded= await encode(JSON.stringify(details));

      await transporter.verify();

      // sending email
      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({"Status":"Failure","Details": err });
        } else {
          return res.send({"Status":"Success","Details":encoded});
        }
      });
    } catch(err) {
       const response = {"Status":"Failure", "Details":err.message};
       return res.status(400).send(response);
    }
}]
```

[image: Terminal output image]

[image: Postman Output image here]

please give me the solution for this error and I tried to solve but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the line -

```
//Create OTP instance in DB
const otp_instance = await OTP.create({ // here....
  otp: otp,
  expiration_time: expiration_time
});
```

You have taken **"const OTP = require('sequelize');"** which means you imported the sequelize package. You have to create a model class import sequelize there and then import that model file here. Eg -

otp.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

const User = sequelize.define('OTP', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  otp: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  expiry: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

Now you can import it here and call create on the model.

```
const OTP = require('otp.js');
const otp_instance = await OTP.create({
  otp: otp,
  expiration_time: expiration_time
});
```

You can read more in the [Official docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer, as you said I have done imported schema file and require 'sequelize' in schema but it is showing same error.

Comment: can u update the new code..

Comment: `const OTP = require('../models/otp');` in the route file

Comment: Try importing sequelize in the main file.

Comment: main file means in index.js? or else in the route file?

Comment: the one you have in question.

Comment: I got solved that but now getting this error Error ` [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: At this code getting that error `else if(result){
      console.log("result: :", result)
           return res.status(200).json({ // errror here
              Status: true,
              message: result.rows
            })
    }
`

Comment: You must have sent the response to client before that line somewhere, you can't send the response twice. Check for it.